# Iterate over keys and use in subprocess in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a script in which I have created a function which reads from a config file.

```
def file_reader():
        config_dict = {}
        configParser = configparser.ConfigParser()

        configParser.read('config.ini')
        for section_name in configParser.sections():
                print('Sections:', section_name)
                print(' Options:', configParser.options(section_name))
                #for (each_key, each_value) in configParser.items(section_name):
                        #config_dict[each_key] = each_value
                config_dict = dict(configParser.items(section_name))
                print(config_dict)
                return config_dict
```

The output I get is as follows:

```
Sections: my-config
 Options: ['path1', 'path2', 'path3']
{'path1': '"/home/asad.javed/stop-services.sh"', 'path2': '"/home/asad.javed/script.py"', 'path3': '"/home/asad.javed/getbps.sh ens6f0"'}
```

My config file looks like this:

```
cat config.ini
[my-config]
path1 = "/home/asad.javed/stop-services.sh"
path2 = "/home/asad.javed/script.py"
path3 = "/home/asad.javed/getbps.sh ens6f0"
```

My config file consists of paths that I need to run as external programs. How can I just use the keys, iterate over them and use in subprocess to run external programs sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

For a given dictionary `d` with values assigned to a series of commands to run:

```
import os
d = {}
exitcodes = []
d['path1'] = '/bin/true'
d['path2'] = '/bin/false'
for c in d.values():
  exitcodes.append( os.system(c) )
```

Comment: Note that blindly executing system-level commands from a dictionary may be hazardous to your system's health.